# Jquery and Bootstrap: animate one panel content from a column to another

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, jQuery, jQueryUI and want to move the three panels to the left when the user answered the question and clicked on "Valider".
The fading effect on the left and right panels are made using a CSS overlay trick (`.opacity-gauche` and `.opacity-droite`)

The effect I'm looking at is:

1. When the user click on "Valider", the three panels shoud be moved to the left.
2. The `.panel-left` div should disapear and then be removed.
3. The `.panel-main` become the `.panel-left`
4. The `.panel.right` become the `.panel.main`
5. A new `.panel-right` should be created and 'sliding' from the right.

[image: Screenshot of the panels]

Code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs" style="position:relative">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center panel-left">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Question <span class="question-numero">1</span> sur <span class="question-nombre-total">5</span></h3></div>
                    <div class="panel-body text-center">
                        <h3 class="question-donnee">5 &times 3 = 15</h3>
                        <div class="input-group mt20 invisible">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">=</div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question-reponse" placeholder="Réponse">
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt20 invisible" id="">Valider</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1000" class="opacity-gauche">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="position:relative">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center panel-main">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Question <span class="question-numero">2</span> sur <span class="question-nombre-total">5</span></h3></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h3 class="question-donnee">5 &times 3</h3>
                        <div class="input-group mt20">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">=</div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question-reponse" placeholder="Réponse">
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt20" id="question-valider">Valider</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs" style="position:relative">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center panel-right">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Question <span class="question-numero">3</span> sur <span class="question-nombre-total">5</span></h3></div>
                    <div class="panel-body text-center">
                        <h3 class="question-donnee">Prochaine question</h3>
                        <div class="input-group mt20 invisible">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">=</div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Réponse">
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt20 invisible" id="question-valider">Valider</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1000" class="opacity-droite">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            $('#question-valider').click(function(ev){
                var panelwidth = $('.panel-main').width();
                //var panelright = $('.panel-right').width();

                $('.panel-left').animate({'width':"0px"}, 400);
                $('.panel-right').css('position','absolute').css('width', panelwidth+'px').animate({'left':"-"+($('.panel-main').parent().width()+15)+"px"}, 400);
                $('.panel-main').css('position','absolute').css('width', panelwidth+'px').animate({'left':"-"+($('.panel-main').parent().width()+15)+"px"}, 400);
            });
        </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Basil

Comment: Please try some JS yourself and post it here. Otherwise, your question is very likely be getting downvotes because you didn't show any effort.

Comment: OK... Here is what I have so far. The left and main panel are working correctly... except that the rows below (not shown above) is moving downward during the animation. The other problem is that, actually, I didn't managed to 'insert' a new panel from the right.